# iOS 10.0, XCODE 8 No Separate siging option for Debug, Releasing Settings and Adhoc provision issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, code-signing, ios10, ad-hoc-distribution

I am getting product signing issue in XCODE 8. Team and adhoc provision has been selected but it says :

> *** has conflicting provisioning settings. **** is automatically signed, but provisioning profile *** has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor.

And

> Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

[image]

Problem 1: No Separate signing option for Debug and Release.

Problem 2: Direct Adhoc provision not running on Device.

Comment: Can you switch to automatic code signing as Xcode suggests?

Comment: Code signing is automatic and provision profile (deprecated) is my app provision. Nothings works. I have enabled my dev signing also.

Comment: The error message states that there is a manually entered provisioning profile uuid. Did you try to remove it and use the auto-generated one?

Comment: I have deleted provision from accounts preferences and re added it. Nothings works still.

Comment: Did you remove the provisioning profile uuid from the build settings of your target/project as well?

Comment: yes, i did. M_G

Answer (score 1):

Same issue of **code signing & provision profile**  occur to me in **Xcode 8.1** .

[image]

It was resolved in 2 steps.

> **i)Disable & reEnabling Automatically manage signing .**

[image]

> **ii)Changing code signing Identity to Target to iOS Developer.**

[image]